# How do you fight subs in Hungry Shark?

Tags: hungry-shark

How do you counter attack submarines in Hungry Shark for the kindle Fire? Is there a certain shark you need to do this?

Comment: We try not to create unnecessary tags here. Since the Kindle Fire runs the Android OS, could you use the android tag in place of the Kindle tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with the Fonz and the Jukebox, the answer seems to be hitting it.

> You need to get up really close to it and run into it. If it keeps
>   shooting you, go away and eat. Come back and it might be turned
>   around. The main point though is to run into it and scuba divers come
>   out but you won't see them. They have guns with them, so watch out!

Also, Boost seems to help add damage when charging into the sub:

> You could crash into it really fast using boost I tried it worked

[Source](http://www.supercheats.com/iphoneipad/questions/hungrysharkevolution/304319/How-can-I-kill-a-submarine.htm)